# Data Being Read as Strings instead of Floats

Tags: string, floating-point

A Pytorch program, which I don't fully understand, produced an output and wrote it into weight.txt. I'm trying to do some further calculations based on this output.
I'd like the output to be interpreted as a list of length 3, each entry of which is a list of floats of length 240.

I use this to load in the data

```
w=open("weight.txt","r")
weight=[]
for number in w:
    weight.append(number)
```

print(len(weight)) yields 3. So far so good.

But then print(len(weight[0])) yields 6141. That's bad!

On closer inspection, it's because weight[0] is being read character-by-character instead of number-by-number. So for example, print(weight[0][0]) yields - instead of -1.327657848596572876e-01. These numbers are separated by single spaces, which are also being read as characters.

How do I fix this?

Thank you

Edit: I tried making a repair function:

```
def repair(S):
    numbers=[]
    num=''
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if S[i]!=' ':
            num+=S[i]
        elif S[i]==' ':
            num=float(num)
            numbers.append(num)
            num=''
        elif i==len(S)-1:
            num+=S[i]
            num=float(num)
            numbers.append(num)
    return numbers
```

Unfortunately, print(repair('123 456')) returns [123.0] instead of the desired [123.0 456.0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't told us what your input file looks like, so it's hard to give an exact answer. But, assuming it looks like this:

```
123 312.8 12
2.5 12.7 32
```

the following program:

```py
w=open("weight.txt","r")
weight=[]
for line in w:
    for n in line.split():
       weight.append(float(n))
print weight
```

will print:

```
[123.0, 312.8, 12.0, 2.5, 12.7, 32.0]
```

which is closer to what you're looking for, I presume?

The crux of the issue here is that `for number in w` in your program simply goes through each line: You have to have another loop to split that line into its constituents and then convert appropriately.

Comment: Thanks, will try that.

As for my repair function though... Why doesn't it work correctly?

Comment: Your `repair` function is not working because the code you wrote for `i==len(S)-1` is never executed: Your first `if` tests for non-space, your second `if` tests for space, so you covered everything possible. Thus, your last branch is never taken.